# Access VBA Compare dates not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having trouble comparing dates. The if statement in my code is saying the endDate is not less even though it is. For example, if the endDate is 2/20/2017 and startDate 2/22/2017 the if statement says endDate is not lest but it is.

```
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date

        startDate = DateValue(Me.dueDateTxt)
        endDate = DateValue(Me.shippedDate)

        If (endDate < startDate) Then
            Debug.Print "It is less"
        Else
            Debug.Print "not less"
        End If
```

I have also tried

```
    If Me.dueDateTxt < Me.ShippedDate Then
    If CDate(startDate) < CDate(endDate) Then        
    If Format(startDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") < Format(endDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
    If DateDiff(d, startDate, endDate) > 0 Then
```

I am missing something somewhere thank you in advance for the help!

EDIT: I figured out what the problem was. I have a function to eliminate holidays and weekends. That function was swaping my startDate and endDate. Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried international date,yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. My dates that are implemented from the text boxes come up as mm/dd/yyyy. Would I have to change the format before comparing them?

Comment: In VBA it is always a good idea to use international date formats. You can use FORMAT to get this.

Answer (score 1):

Your first block of code works fine for me.

Have you set the format of the text boxes(?) as 'Short Date' for example?

Comment: I figured out what was going on. I have a function to eliminate holidays and weekends. That function was swaping my startDate and endDate. Frustrating that it took all this time to find it. Thank you for your response and suggestion.